# OOP PHP - JSON-encoding an object

Tags: php, json, oop

I want to create a simple class that I can use and encode as a `json` string. My goal is to encode a json object with info about all my photos on the page. Never used object oriented php before, but I gave it a shot:

```
class Photo
{
public $file;
public $date;

function __construct($filename, $datetime) 
{
    $file = $filename;
    $date = $datetime;
}

}
```

Looping through my photos and creating a new instance of the class for each photo:

```
$photo = new Photo($filename, $date);
```

2 problems: `echo json_encode($photo);` shows me that filename and datetime are null. And when I use `echo json_encode($photo);`, I will only get the last photo printed, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answers are correct you need to use **$this**.

Try this:

```
class Photos {
   private $photos = array();

   function add_photo($filename, $date) {
      $this->photos[] = array('filename' => $filename, 'date' => $date);
      return $this;
   }

   function get_all() {
      return json_encode($this->photos);
   }
}


$my_photos = new Photos();

$my_photos->add_photo('test.jpg', '2011-01-01');

echo $my_photos->get_all();
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention, you can also chain up the add_photo method:

```
$my_photos->add_photo('test.jpg', '2011-01-01')->add_photo('test.jpg', '2011-01-01');
```

Comment: just a little mistake of `'` . Use `$my_photos->add_photo('test.jpg', '2011-01-01');`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use class member by using $this->varName in your class

So you constructor should be as

```
function __construct($filename, $datetime) 
{
    $this->file = $filename;
    $this->date = $datetime;
}
```

as @code_burgar said : need to use array

```
$photo[] = new Photo($filename, $date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to be sure to reference your instance variables with `$this`. For example:

```
function __construct($filename, $datetime) 
{
    $this->file = $filename;
    $this->date = $datetime;
}
```

I'd encourage you to read [PHP's OOP Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
class Photo
{
 public $file;
 public $date;

 function __construct($filename, $datetime) 
   {
       $this->file = $filename;
       $this->date = $datetime;
   }

}
```

And if you want to preserve all your photo objects, you can do

```
$photos[] = new Photo($file,$date);
```

and then access them using a `foreach()` loop

Answer (score 1):

The others answered the question to your first problem.  To update members of an object, you must use `$this` in the context of the object.  Externally, use the variable referencing the object since your members are public:

```
class Photo {
   public $file;
   public $date;
}
$photo = new Photo;
$photo->file = 'file';
$photo->date = time();
echo json_encode($photo);
```

It is not good design practice to expose members of an object publicly, but `json_encode()` will not add non-public members to the json string, so you need your own encode method to go this route:

```
class Photo {
   private $file;
   private $date;
   public function __construct($file, $date) {
      $this->file = $file;
      $this->date = $date;
   }
   public function __encode() {
      $json = new stdClass;
      foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $name => $value) {
         $this->$name = $value;
      }
      return json_encode($json);
   }
}
```

Your second question seems to imply that you may want multiple photos all stored as a Photo object.  You can just put multiple `Photo` objects into an array.